# ng-list in angularJS is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in place

```
<input class="fill" name="keywords" ng-model="textbook.keywords" 
type="text" ng-list=","  ng-required="true"></input>
```

where textbook.keywords is an array of strings.

I expect the above code to create a text box filled with comma separated values of the array, textbook.keywords. Instead, the textbox is empty. I made sure textbook.keywords has values in it by debugging.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gkq9U9z54RqleSieSOQl?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. It is in the code you're hiding from us.

Comment: The `<input>` element is self-closing; `</input>` is illegal HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** Please check whether the library properly added in `index.html`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**Second:** Please check whether the `ng-app` is added properly in HTML:

```
<html ng-app="listApp">
```

**Third:** Please check whether the `ng-controller` is added properly in HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="ListCtrl">
```

**Forth:** The `app.js` should should contain the following minimum code:

```
var app = angular.module('listApp', []);

app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.textbook = {
    keywords: ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
  };
});
```

**Fifth:** Don't forget to add `app.js` in `index.html`

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**Final:**  The working code snippet is added here:

```js
var app = angular.module('listApp', []);

app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.textbook = {
    keywords: ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="listApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <input class="fill" name="keywords" ng-model="textbook.keywords" 
type="text" ng-list=","  ng-required="true"> 
  </body>

</html>
```